# IntegrityError at /profile NOT NULL constraint failed: tutorapp_profile.user_id

Tags: python, django

I am making an app for finding tutors where tutors need to log in and post their jobs in the web application. While developing the profile section for tutors, i am unable to add a feature of updating or uploading a new profile bio and profile picture. I'm new to django

Here is my model of Profile in models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image= models.ImageField(default = 'default.jpg',upload_to='profile_pics')
    bio=models.CharField(default = 'no bio',max_length=350)

    def __str__ (self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

and its model form

```
class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields =['image','bio',]

    def clean(self):
        super(UpdateProfile, self).clean()
        return self.cleaned_data
```

view of profile views.py

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        p_form = UpdateProfile()

    context = {
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request,'profile.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('home', views.index, name='home'),
    path('signup', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('postskill', views.postskill, name='postskill'),
    path('profile', views.profile, name='profile'),
]
```

template of profile.html

```
<img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{user.profile.image.url}}" height="100" width="100">
<h5> First Name: {{user.first_name}} </h5>
<h5> Last Name: {{user.last_name}} </h5>
<h5> Username: {{user.username}} </h5>
<h5> Email: {{user.email}} </h5>
<p> Bio: {{user.profile.bio}} </p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onClick="myFunction()"> UpdateProfile</button>
<div id ="hide">
  {% csrf_token %}
<form method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ p_form|crispy }}
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update </button>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And when i press the update button in browser. Error shown:

```
IntegrityError at /profile

NOT NULL constraint failed: tutorapp_profile.user_id

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile
Django Version:     3.0.3
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:    

NOT NULL constraint failed: tutorapp_profile.user_id

Exception Location:     /home/arpan/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 396
Python Executable:  /home/arpan/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/bin/python
Python Version:     3.8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill in the `user` field if that profile. If you want to link it to the logged user, you can work with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.instance.user = request.user
            p_form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        p_form = UpdateProfile()

    context = {
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request,'profile.html',context)
```

or in case you want to update the (already existing) `profile` of the logged in user:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p_form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            p_form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        p_form = UpdateProfile()

    context = {
        'p_form': p_form
    }
    return render(request,'profile.html',context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: Usually a `Form` or a `ModelForm` ends with a `…Form` suffix,
> to avoid collisions with the name of the model, and to make it clear that we are
> working with a *form*. Therefore it might be better to use `UpdateProfileForm` instead of
> <s>`UpdateProfile`</s>.

Comment: I filled the user field in my profile view. This error showed up : IntegrityError at /profile

UNIQUE constraint failed: tutorapp_profile.user_id.. please help

Comment: @arpandhakal: well since you use a `OneToOneField`, that means that two profiles can *not* refer to the same `User`, so you already have a `Profile` that refers to the `User` that you selected.

Comment: thank you very much. Can you please tell me what can i do to update data in Profile of a user that already has a Profile

Comment: @arpandhakal: you select the profile, and pass it through the `instance=...` parameter of the model form.